# Displaying list of items´ properties grouped in labels in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, label, group

I am trying to display all objects´ properties of a List in different labels grouped by one of their properties.

Here is my class definition:

```
public class User
        {
            public  string Username { get; set; }
            public  string IP { get; set; }
            public  string Levels { get; set; }
        }
```

Here I deserialize users into the List bringing them from http request to API:

```
var users = new List<User>();
       for (int i = 0; i < cuenta; i++)
           {
              await getAllUsers(i,users);
           }

 

private async Task getAllUsers(int count, List<User> users)
        {
            var requestURI = new HttpRequestMessage();
            string url = "https:...;
            requestURI.RequestUri = new Uri(url);
            requestURI.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
            requestURI.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage responseURI = await client.SendAsync(requestURI);
            if (responseURI.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                
                Debug.WriteLine("Get Users OK");
                var UserString = await responseURI.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine("Users in DLT: " + UserString);
                var userGET = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(UserString);
                users.Add(userGET);
                Debug.WriteLine(users[0].IP); // Works correct

            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Users GET request failed");
            }
        }
```

I would like to display all users properties (Username, IP and Levels) of the list "users" in different labels grouped by the different levels of them.

Comment: Have you read the docs on Grouping?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#grouping

Comment: Yes, but in a text cell you cant display two propperties of an item. Detail doesnt accept two parameters

Comment: Then use a ViewCell with two Labels instead.  A mockup of your UI might help explain what you're trying to achieve